# How to add the values in SQL Server 2008 database using .CSV file

Tags: sql-server, csv, mfc

i have created one dialog based application in MFC.
Here i connected the database connection using connection string which is

```
CDatabase database;
CString SqlString;
CString sDriver = "SQL Server";
CString sDsn;
CString sFile = "D:\\rajesh\\Examine.mdf";      

sDsn.Format("Driver={SQLServer};Server=xxxx;Database=sree;Uid=sa;Pwd=ramesh@123");
```

after connect the database i have to insert the values using .CSV file how to do that.I already created database and Tables.

please help me solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start here:   https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=import+.csv+to+sql+server&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=import+.csv+to+sql+server&gs_l=hp...0l5.0.0.2.83212330...........0.dzQPdm11ayU

Comment: i want write the code in visual studio 2008 not in SQL server.

Comment: In that case you should probably tag the language you are writing in, to attract the attention of experts in that language.   That, and change the google search to include it.